# I'm trying to load data from mysql in textview

Tags: android, mysql, textview, load

This is my code. Please help me to find the mistake. I loaded all reclamations in a `ListView` and it works correctly but when I click on a single reclamation to show details it doesn't work, it shows me the layout but without displaying informations in textviews.

```
 public class EditReclamationActivity extends Activity {

                TextView txtName;

                TextView txtType;
                TextView txtDesc;
                String rid;

                Progress Dialog
                private ProgressDialog pDialog;                

                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();                

                private static final String url_reclamation_details = "http://192.168.1.67/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

                private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
                private static final String TAG_RECLAMATION = "reclamation";
                private static final String TAG_RID = "rid";
                private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
                private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
                private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.edit_reclamation);

                    Intent i = getIntent();                  
                    rid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_RID);               

                    new GetReclamationDetails().execute();

                    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
                    txtType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type1);
                    txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description1);              
                }
        class GetReclamationDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {                   
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditReclamationActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading reclamation details. Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();            
                }         

                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {                       
                           try {

                               List<NameValuePair> pars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                               pars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rid", rid));                              

                              final JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                      url_reclamation_details, "GET", pars);            

                               Log.d("Single Rec Details", json.toString());
                               final int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                   public void run() {                                      

                                       if (success == 1) {            
                                           try {

                                               JSONArray recObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RECLAMATION);         

                                               JSONObject reclamation = recObj.getJSONObject(0);    
                                               txtName.setText(reclamation.getString(TAG_NAME));                            txtType.setText(reclamation.getString(TAG_TYPE));                            txtDesc.setText(reclamation.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));            

                                           } catch (JSONException e) {

                                           }
                                       } else {

                                       }
                                   }
                               });
                           } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }                  

                    return null;
                }           

                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {         
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }   
        }
```

[This is the message error, data are loaded from mysql but not in android:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vinW4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your calling `new GetReclamationDetails().execute();`before you `findViewsById()`. Also, update your UI in `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate`, and try call your view like: `ActivityName.class.yourView.setText()` Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Declare textview before settext from method.

```
txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
txtType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type1);
txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description1);   

new GetReclamationDetails().execute();
```